# Spring Integration - The 'currentComponent' (routerFlow) is a one-way 'MessageHandler' and it isn't appropriate to configure 'outputChannel'

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have implemented a RecipientListRouter shown below -

```
    @Bean
    public RecipientListRouter routerFlow() {
        RecipientListRouter router = new RecipientListRouter();
        router.setIgnoreSendFailures(true);
        router.setApplySequence(true);
        router.addRecipient("channelChkn", "headers.get('eventSubType').contains('CHKN')");
        router.addRecipient("channelBkd", "headers.get('eventSubType').contains('BKD')");
        router.addRecipient("channelBrd", "headers.get('eventSubType').contains('BRD')");
        router.addRecipient("channelAciRecCncl", "headers.get('eventSubType').contains('ACI-REC-CNCL')");
        router.addRecipient("channelSeatAsgn", "headers.get('eventSubType').contains('SEATNBR-')");
        router.addRecipient("channelDeboard", "headers.get('isDeBoarded') == true");
        router.setDefaultOutputChannelName(IntegrationContextUtils.NULL_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME);
        LOGGER.info("********************* RecipientListRouter *********************" + router.getRecipients());
        return router;
    }
```

My event flow is

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow baseEventFlow() {

        return IntegrationFlows.from(Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(kafkaMessageListenerContainer))
                .filter(filterMessage, "rejectPastData")
                .transform(aciMessageTransformer, "parserXMLMessage")
                .route(routerFlow())
                // executor used to parallelise the multiple subscribe execution
                .publishSubscribeChannel(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                        pubsub -> pubsub.subscribe(flow -> flow.channel("pubCountEvntChannel"))
                                .subscribe(flow -> flow.channel("pubTravlerEventChannel")))
                .get();

    }
```

I am getting the Bean Creation exception - The 'currentComponent' (routerFlow) is a one-way 'MessageHandler' and it isn't appropriate to configure 'outputChannel'

It seems that after route we can't invoke any handler method in the parent flow. But in my scenario the handler in the route processes the data and sets a value in the java object that needs to be used in the main flow to publish to the down-line channels.

Please suggest how to achieve this

##Edited##

If I add the below recipient in the router list then I believe the the channel will always be among the list of recipients and I can do the processing after the event is processed by the handlers.  Please confirm if the below recipient will be added at the end of the router list.

```
router.addRecipient("pubSubChannel");
```

Also, if the message header doesn't match with any of the values then we are sending it to the default NULL channel, discarding the message.

If we add the above "pubSubChannel" recipient then what will be the impact of the un-matched messages. Do I have to handle the unmatched messages in the pubSubEventChannel?

Please suggest

**###EDITED**

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow baseEventFlow() {

        return IntegrationFlows.from(Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(kafkaMessageListenerContainer))
                .filter(filterMessage, "rejectPastData")
                .transform(aciMessageTransformer, "parserXMLMessage")
                .gateway(eventFlow())
                .handle (test())
                .get()
   }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow eventFlow() {
        return f -> f.route(routerFlow());
    }

    @Bean
    public RecipientListRouter routerFlow() {
        RecipientListRouter router = new RecipientListRouter();
        router.setIgnoreSendFailures(true);
        router.setApplySequence(true);
        router.addRecipient("channelChkn", "headers.get('eventSubType').contains('CHKN')");
        router.addRecipient("channelBkd", "headers.get('eventSubType').contains('BKD')");
        router.addRecipient("channelBrd", "headers.get('eventSubType').contains('BRD')");
        router.addRecipient("channelAciRecCncl", "headers.get('eventSubType').contains('ACI-REC-CNCL')");
        router.addRecipient("channelSeatAsgn", "headers.get('eventSubType').contains('SEATNBR-')");
        // router.addRecipient("channelSeatAsgn","headers.get('eventSubType').contains('SEATNBR-ASSIGN')");
        // router.addRecipient("channelSeatAsgn","headers.get('eventSubType').contains('SEATNBR-CHG')");
        router.addRecipient("channelDeboard", "headers.get('isDeBoarded') == true");
        //router.setDefaultOutputChannelName(IntegrationContextUtils.NULL_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME);
        LOGGER.info("********************* RecipientListRouter *********************" + router.getRecipients());
        return router;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot continue a flow after a router.

If the various flows downstream of the router return a result, you must use a `.gateway(...)` element to invoke the router; the result will then return to the main flow.

Comment: Thank you Gary, could you please provide an example

Comment: See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-subflows). Scroll down to `Sometimes, you need to refer to an existing IntegrationFlow @Bean from the .subFlowMapping(). The following example shows how to do so:` . You would use `.gateway(flowThatStartsWithRouter())` directly in your main flow.

Comment: `return f -> f.routeToRecipients(...)` - again - see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-routers).

Comment: Thank you Gary, I have edited my original question and made the changes. Just a quick one how can we set unmatched messages to send to default parent flow in the RecipientListRouter.

Comment: If you just want to ignore such messages, set the gateway `replyTimeout` to 0; if you want to send the unmatched messages themselves back to the main flow, send them to a flow that has a "bridge to nowhere" `f -> f.bridge()`.